# python's argument parser printing the argument name in upper case

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write usage/help for my python script using the `argparse` library.

This is my sample code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='My description')

parser.add_argument(
        "-r", "--remote", 
        help="help message")

parser.print_help()
```

Output:

```
usage: [-h] [-r REMOTE]

My description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r REMOTE, --remote REMOTE
                        help message
```

I have no idea why it is printing `REMOTE` after the `-r` and `--remote` switches in the above output.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here or what should I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at the *metavar*; it is autogenerated from the option string to form a placeholder. It tells the user that it is there that they need to fill in a value.

You can set an explicit metavar value with the [`metavar` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#metavar):

> When `ArgumentParser` generates help messages, it needs some way to refer to each expected argument. By default, `ArgumentParser` objects use the dest value as the “name” of each object. By default, for positional argument actions, the dest value is used directly, and for optional argument actions, the dest value is uppercased.

You see it because your argument takes a value; if you expected it to be a toggle, use [`action='store_true'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action); in that case the option defaults to `False` unless the user specifies the switch.

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
...         description='My description')
>>> parser.add_argument("-r", "--remote", action='store_true', help="help message")
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-r', '--remote'], dest='remote', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help='help message', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] [-r]

My description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -r, --remote  help message
>>> opts = parser.parse_args([])
>>> opts.remote
False
>>> opts = parser.parse_args(['-r'])
>>> opts.remote
True
```

Comment: Thanks. By setting `Metavar =""` explicitly solves my problem. I don't want to give `action=store_true`  since  I want the values after -r in my script.

Comment: @RBH The metavar hints to your script's users that a value goes there. Otherwise, they will assume that `-r` is a `store_true`, even if it isn't set up that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `action`.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='My description')

parser.add_argument(
        "-r", "--remote", action="store_true", # add action
        help="help message")

parser.print_help()
usage: -c [-h] [-r]

My description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -r, --remote  help message
```